# ETL Scala script got exception

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, etl

I am writing simple ETL process in scala script and running as 'spark-shell -i rawetl.scala' However got exception "Table not found BaseTable". I also checked file, it is picking correctly.

Here is the sample code

```
import java.io.File
import sqlContext.implicits._
import scala.io.Source
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import sys.process._
case class pageRow(affiliateid : String , pageurl : String, alertedbrandsafety : String, blockedbrandsafety : String, grossimpressions : String, spider_bot : String, invalidbrowser : String ,outlieractivity : String , day : String)

object batch_nht {
    def main() {
        processRawNHT()
    }

    def processRawNHT() {

        val rawFile = "hadoop fs -ls /tmp/XXX/rawDB/" #| "tail -1" !!
        val fileName = rawFile.substring(rawFile.indexOf("/"))
        val filePathName = "hdfs://AAAAA:8020" + fileName.trim()
        println(filePathName)

        val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("analyzeBlog"))
        val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

        val inviewraw = sc.textFile(filePathName).map(_.split(",")).map(x=>x.map(_.replace("\"","")))
        val base_people = inviewraw.map{r => if(r(13) == null || r(13).trim.isEmpty) (r(5) ,r(32), r(48), r(49),r(14), r(71), r(72), r(73),r(0)) else (r(5) ,r(32), r(48), r(49),r(14), r(71), r(72), r(73),r(0))}

        val logs_base_page_schemaRDD = base_people.map(p => pageRow(p._1, p._2, p._3, p._4,p._5, p._6, p._7, p._8,p._9)).toDF()

        logs_base_page_schemaRDD.registerTempTable("baseTable")

        sqlContext.sql("select * from baseTable").collect().foreach(println)
    }
}
batch_nht.main()
```

NOTE: If I run the bellow commands one by one in spark shell(without script), I got correct output without any exception.

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._

val inviewraw = sc.textFile("hdfs://AAAAA:8020/tmp/XXX/rawDB/rawFile.csv").map(_.split(",")).map(x=>x.map(_.replace("\"","")))
val base_people = inviewraw.map{r => if(r(13) == null || r(13).trim.isEmpty) (r(5) ,r(32), r(48), r(49),r(14), r(71), r(72), r(73),r(0)) else (r(5) ,r(32), r(48), r(49),r(14), r(71), r(72), r(73),r(0))}

case class pageRow(affiliateid : String , pageurl : String, alertedbrandsafety : String, blockedbrandsafety : String, grossimpressions : String, spider_bot : String, invalidbrowser : String ,outlieractivity : String , day : String)

val logs_base_page_schemaRDD = base_people.map(p => pageRow(p._1, p._2, p._3, p._4,p._5, p._6, p._7, p._8,p._9)).toDF()

--create table
logs_base_page_schemaRDD.registerTempTable("baseTable")
sqlContext.sql("select * from baseTable").collect().foreach(println)
```

Please suggest what goes wrong? in script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code snippet which is tested. Your approach will not work for Programmatic approach using scala.

```
import java.io.File
import sqlContext.implicits._
import scala.io.Source
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import sys.process._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType,StructField,StringType};

object batch_nht {
    def main() {
        processRawNHT()
    }

    def processRawNHT() {
        val rawFile = "hadoop fs -ls /user/cloudera/cards/" #| "tail -1" !!
        val fileName = rawFile.substring(rawFile.indexOf("/"))
        val filePathName = "hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020" + fileName.trim()
        println(filePathName)
        val schemaString = "color|suit|pip"
        val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
        val deck = sc.textFile(filePathName).map(_.split("\\|"))
        val schema =
            StructType(
            schemaString.split("\\|").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)))
        val base_deckRDD = deck.map{r => Row(r(0), r(1), r(2))}
        val cardsDataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(base_deckRDD, schema)
        cardsDataFrame.registerTempTable("deck_of_cards")
        val firstTen = sqlContext.sql("select * from deck_of_cards limit 10")
        firstTen.map(r => (r(0), r(1), r(2))).collect().foreach(println)
    }
}

batch_nht.main()
```

Comment: It is just an example. As I already mentioned "I also checked file, it is picking correctly."

Comment: Edited with working script. Please it me know if it helps.

Comment: This is awesome. I changed accordig to my stuff and it is working. This is my first scala script. thx a lot.